# Inheritance, Generics, and Protocols in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, swift-protocols

I have a generic class of the form:

```
class BaseClass<T> {
    var prop: T
    ...
}
```

I then have multiple subclasses of the form:

```
class SubClassOne: BaseClass<SomeSubClass> {
    ...
}

class SubClassTwo: BaseClass<SomeOtherSubClass> {
    ...
}
```

Where the type parameters `SomeSubClass` and `SomeOtherSubClass` both inherit from a common base class `SomeBaseClass`.

I now want to define a variable to store instances of both `SubClassOne` and `SubClassTwo`. I have tried many possibilities:

```
var obj: BaseClass
var obj: BaseClass<SomeBaseClass>
var obj: BaseClass<Any>
```

But the first attempt results in the error `Reference to generic type 'BaseClass' requires arguments in <...>`, and the other two result in the error `Cannot assign value of type 'SubClassOne' to type ...` when trying to assign a value. I even tried to trick the Swift compiler into inferring the type for me by initializing an array:

```
var testArray = [SubClassOne(), SubClassTwo()]
```

But even this failed, resulting in the error `Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to [Any]; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional`. Indeed, the only type annotation that successfully allows storage of both SubClasses is `Any` or `AnyObject`. Is it possible to store these instances with a more specific type? If not, why?

The reason it's important to do so is that I ultimately want to get the property `prop` from the stored variable `obj`. I am unable to do so if `obj` is stored as `Any`. I am also unable to simply cast it to `SubClassOne` or `SubClassTwo` because the method itself where I am trying to access the properties is a generic method, and which of `SubClassOne` or `SubClassTwo` to cast to depends on the generic type parameter of the method:

```
func castObj<T>(asType: T.Type) {
    (self.obj as? T).prop
}
```

Which would be called as: `castObj(asType: SubClassOne.self)` or `castObj(asType: SubClassTwo.self)`. However, we run into the same problem: the only generic type parameter constraint I can define that accepts both `SubClassOne` and `SubClassTwo` is `Any`, and then the Swift compiler complains: `Value of type 'T' has no member 'prop'`.

As a workaround I tried to define a protocol that encapsulates the desired property:

```
protocol HasProp {
    var prop: SomeBaseClass { get }
}
```

Then I added this to the declaration of `SubClassOne` and `SubClassTwo`. However this resulted in still another error: `Type 'SubClassOne' does not conform to protocol 'HasProp'`. This confuses me as well, since `SubClassOne` and `SubClassTwo` both inherit `prop` from `BaseClass<SomeSubClass>` and so actually do conform to the protocol.

In summary:

1. Is it possible to store instances of `SubClassOne` and `SubClassTwo` with a more specific type that gives access to properties of `BaseClass`? If not, why?
2. Why do the SubClasses not conform to the protocol as expected?
3. How can I change the design to attain my desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at the moment the function `castObj` has no type constraints for its generic parameter, `T`. By giving a type constraint of `BaseClass` you should be fine, since `BaseClass` has both properties.

```
func castObj<T: BaseClass>(asType: T.Type) {
    (self.obj as? T).propOne
    (self.obj as? T).propTwo
}
```

Comment: I've tried this as well - I run into the same problem as when trying to define a type for `obj` in the first place. The type constraint of simply `BaseClass` doesn't work, since `Reference to generic type 'BaseClass' requires arguments in <...>`. If I try, for example `BaseClass<Any, Any>`, we're back to the same old error `Cannot convert value of type 'SubClassOne.Type' to expected argument type 'BaseClass<Any, Any>.Type'` when I try to call the method by `castObj(asType: SubClassOne.self)`

Comment: Is this function defined inside `BaseClass` or outside of it?

Comment: It's defined outside of it

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the type of `propTwo` was common to both subclasses and the type of `propOne` was specialized. Make your design reflect that.

[was]

```
class BaseClass<T,U> {
    var propOne: T
    var propTwo: U
    ...
}
class SubClassOne: BaseClass<SomeSubClass, SomeClass> {}
class SubClassTwo: BaseClass<SomeOtherSubClass, SomeClass> {}
```

[could be]

```
class BaseClass<U> {
    var propTwo: U
    ...
}
class SubClassOne<T>: BaseClass<SomeClass> {
    var propOne: T
    ...
}
class SubClassTwo<T>: BaseClass<SomeClass> {
    var propOne: T
    ...
}
```

The point is to keep common things in the base class and compose your specializations.

Comment: I don't think I should make `SubClassOne` or `SubClassTwo` generics themselves, because they are each defined for `SomeSubClass` and `SomeOtherSubClass` specifically, using methods and properties of those two classes. They are not meant to be created with different type parameters. I agree this approach would give access to `propTwo` since then both SubClasses would be of type `BaseClass<SomeClass>`, but I'm not sure it would help access `propOne`.

Comment: I am also thinking this question could have been simplified by removing the second type parameter (`U`/`SomeClass`) altogether. I think it's extraneous and maybe not relevant to the problem, but just confuses the issue.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

There's a fundamental misconception that SubclassOne and SubclassTwo are in the same inheritance hierarchy. Because of the generic type, they inherit from different base classes. You cannot mix and match them.

Think about it. With inheritance you should be able to use any subclass anywhere where you have the base class, so in your test example:

```
var testArray = [SubClassOne(), SubClassTwo()]
```

What type would the right hand side of the following expressions have to be?

testArray[0].prop = something

And this one

testArray[1].prop = something;

In `SubClassOne`, the type of `prop` is `SomeSubClass` and in `SubClassTwo` the type of `prop` must be `SomeOtherSubClass`.

The only way for you to get this to work is for `prop` to be declared as `SomeBaseClass` and that removes the necessity for `BaseClass` to be generic.

**Edit**

Why doesn't the protocol work?

The problem with the protocol is that you define the property as having the type of the base class but it is read/write. A property in an implementation of the protocol cannot fulfill the contract with a property that is specialised to one of the subclasses because other bits of code need to be able to assign any instance of the base class to the property.

```
protocol MyProtocol
{
    var prop: BaseClass
}

struct MyImplementation: MyProtocol
{
    var prop: SubClass
}

class BaseClass {}
class SubClass: BaseClass {}
class DifferentSubClass: BaseClass {}

var instance: MyProtocol = MyImplementation()

instance.prop = DifferentSubClass() 
// Should be legal because the protocol says so but the type of prop in instance is SubClass.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly a problem for a protocol with a property which is both gettable and settable. But curiously Swift does not even allow a protocol with a read-only property to be conformed to by a class with a property of the same name and a type which is a sub-class of the protocol's property's type (if that makes sense). I don't really get why this should be disallowed. For example: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5991c36977dbb8209e7b17c1

Comment: That link has a mistake - this one's correct: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5991c5e377dbb8209e7b17c6